# Windows 8 Preview Samples

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have downloaded the Metro Style Application Sample that is available on the Microsoft Web Site. There are lots of examples that shows how you can interact with the hardware device (sensors,gps,etc). I have of course downloaded the Windows 8 Developer preview to execute those examples. My question is : how can I test those samples that uses the device hardware (gps, accelerometer) or that accesses to the phone features (sms,etc) using the emulator?
At the moment there are not devices that support windows 8 (the first phone will probably come out this autumn) ?
I'd like to start to develop some metro style applications to be ready when windows 8 store will be online but using just the emulator is a big limitation isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. There are slate devices that can run the Windows 8 Dev Preview just fine.

If you are unable to get one of these, one option is to create your own interfaces for all the devices. Underneath you can have two implementations.

1. First one, you connect to the actual underlying devices via the Windows 8 APIs. Sure you won't be able to test these until you have a device but such is life.
2. The second implementation can be a dummy one. For example, you can have a thread running and every 2-3 seconds publishing some GPS event.

That way you at least have some dummy device data coming in that you can test with for the time being.

Comment: basically Do I need to Mock the devices?